# Using ASP.NET Core Identity with AJAX returns 401

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-7.0

I have a site which has a web project (.NET 6) and a Web API (.NET 7).
I am using Identity which is set up in the API. When I log in the `.AspNetCore.Session` cookie is set in the browser. If I make a request to the API using `HttpClient` and the endpoint has the `[Authorize]` attribute, then this works correctly.

However some of my requests are being sent through AJAX and these fail with an http 401 Unauthorized error.

Originally both methods were returning a 401 error but after some alterations to the middleware order, the http client method now works.

I have done some research and there are a number of reasons why the AJAX request could fail.

I have tried updating the AJAX request with crossDomain and withCredentials enabled.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        method: 'GET',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: successCallback,
    })
```

I have checked that CORS is set up correctly.

```
app.UseCors(cors =>
            {
                cors
                .WithOrigins(new string[] { "https://localhost:7268" })
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
            });
```

I have updated the authentication so the cookie's same site property is Lax which should apparently allow it to be sent to other domains.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder()
                {
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                    SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
                };

                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = redirectContext =>
                    {
                        redirectContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

if I inspect the request in chrome dev tools it appears that the session cookie is being included in the header.

If I remove the [Authorize] attribute on the API controller the endpoint is hit but if I inspect the identity user it is empty.

Both Get and Post requests are doing the same thing.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have tested your configuration, It works well, before you access the action protected by [Authorize] attribute, Have you logged in successfully?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your reply.  It turns out that there was an issue with how I was logging in to identity.  If I logged in via ajax then ajax calls would work.  if I logged in using httpclient then only httpclient calls would work.  There's probably a better solution but I have just left both login methods in which seems to work.